# javascript / jquery using a variable to reference different parts of a json/xml object

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, reference

I'd like to create a function which can cope with JSON in the following nested format. The keys will change ie
conditions - could be anything and the subcondition key could be anything but the structure remains the same.

My function is defined as

```
  populatePageEditorMenu: function (jsonPath, topLevel, childLevel){
```

and called by

```
 populatePageEditorMenu("http://localhost/data/conditions.json", 'conditions', 'subcondition' );
```

this allows me to point to different bit of json with different keys with the SAME structure however I cant seem to get the subcondition key to be configurable my syntax is'nt quite right.

With the following JSON

```
{
    "conditions": [
        {
            "condition": [
                {
                    "name": "TOP",
                    "subcondition": [
                        {
                            "name": "CHILD1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I can reference the top level conditions as such using square brackets..

```
$.getJSON(jsonPath,
                    function(data) {
                        $.each(data[topLevel], function(topentryIndex, entry) {
```

This works OK !

The problematic subsection doesnt seem to work I had prior to this using paramaterized used the following ...
The square brackets dont work here ...

```
$.each(this.subcondition, function(entryIndex, entry) { ....
```

I've posted a more complete version on the jsfiddle the JSON can be seen in the CSS view.

Reference - http://jsfiddle.net/wmitchell/QRkxd/

Comment: The code and JSON you posted don't go together at all...

Comment: tried to clear it up a bit .. shows the calling of the function and the definition. A more complete post can be found on the jsfiddle ref

Comment: Your jsFiddle isn't too much help without `jsonPath` being set...

Comment: It wont actually work - I was more just using it to show the code a bit more clearly - assume the jsonPath points to the content in the CSS

Comment: At what do you want to point at with `this.action` and `this.subaction` ? Don't see there anything like this inside the json.

Comment: I had initally hard coded this for another bit of json which has action(s) and subaction in the same way the json posted has conditions - im trying to write this to be generic. I've updated this jsfiddle so its more understandable ... apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for looking at this guys apologies it was probably hard for me to explain what I was after.

Basically I wanted to know if I could use variables to represent the fields I was trying to access within an object

I was able to use things like

```
$.each(data[topLevel], function(topentryIndex, entry) {
```

Where toplevel was a string rep of a field in the object

and

```
 this["variablename"]
```

to do it

Thanks for looking at this. I had a few mistakes in my json also which probably didnt help.
Not sure If I should leave this post around or delete it.